# Openlayers Overview and OpenLayers versions

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have installed OpenLayers and the Openlayers Overview plug-ins but I am not sure if they are working. I can create new 'open' layers from the Openlayers plug-in drop down, but when I try to add a map from the 'Openlayers Overview' window it gives an error stating that '*The version  of Openlayers Plugin is 0.93, need be version 0.42!*'.

Does this 'Overview Add map' do the same thing as the plugin menu options, in which case I guess there is no problem, I just won't use it or should it something else?

Also, the layers don't have a properties dialog. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Openlayers Overview is deprecated by now.
Just pick a new layer from the menu bar.

And you are right that the OL layers don't have properties.