# OpenLayers Plugin won't render maps correctly

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

In QGIS, I've created a map by adding a Tiger layer of my county, a KML of a water feature, and a geo-coded CSV of points of interest. I'm trying to add another layer using the OpenLayers Overview.

When the Overview is open in my sidebar, it correctly identifies in its small window the location that I am viewing in the main window. However, when I try to add a layer, the I instead getting a repeating Google map that just appears as a band across the middle of the screen instead of a layer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I've never seen this kind of behavior.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what is happening:
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/QgLkVhb.png)

I took this screenshot after switching the project and all of the layers to EPSG:3857 as Andre Joost was describing below.

Answer (score 2):

The **Openlayers Overview** plugin is outdated, and does not work with the current **OpenLayers Plugin**.

See also [Openlayers Overview and OpenLayers versions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31526/openlayers-overview-and-openlayers-versions)

I'm not sure what goes wrong with your data, but with OpenLayers plugin the project CRS should always be EPSG:3857.